# How to add a class to card and remove once clicked outside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a couple of cards that will be cloned and I want to add a class when clicked inside those cards and replace it when clicked outside and I want to keep a certain class called metadata unchanged

**my fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/abdotamer3/s57jauxw/27/

### My detection function:

```
$(".card").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("viewItemInactive");
    $(this).addClass("viewItemActive");
});
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".card") === false) {
        $(".card").not(".MetaData").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("viewItemActive");
            $(this).addClass("viewItemInactive");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can just add this 2 lines to on click

```
$(".card").removeClass('randomClass');
$(this).addClass('randomClass');
```

So this will add class when you click on a card, and remove it when you click on another card and also add it again to the one you clicked.

So the on click would than be like this:

```
$(".card").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("viewItemInactive");
    $(this).addClass("viewItemActive");
    $(".card").removeClass('randomClass');
    $(this).addClass('randomClass');
});
```